# How can I rename a PostgreSQL table with zero downtime?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table called `orders`. Every few minutes I need to sync it to a warehouse. My strategy is to prepare a new table called `orders_tmp` that is the latest sync of the warehouse.

I then want to do:

```
alter table orders rename to throwaway_value;
alter table orders_tmp rename to orders;
drop table throwaway_value;
```

There will be clients actively sending API requests to fetch the data from the orders table, and Python ORMs expecting there to be an orders table.

When I run the two alter queries, it takes about 300ms seconds after the `orders` table is renamed before the `orders_tmp` table is renamed to `orders`. This is too long, as it means there doesn't exist an orders table for 300ms every 5 minutes.

Is there a way to guarantee that there is always an orders table, as I swap them out? For example, some way to make the transactions locking so that any requests like `select * from orders limit 10` will wait until the rename is complete?

Comment: Why not actually sync the `orders` table by doing queries against the orders_tmp table?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver could you clarify what that would entail?

Comment: `INSERT INTO orders SELECT ot.*  FROM orders_tmp AS ot LEFT JOIN orders AS o on o.<pk> = it.<pk> WHERE o.<pk> IS NULL` to get new items into `orders` table. Use reverse with `DELETE` to delete items from `orders` table. `UPDATE` would depend on something like an updated timestamp to distinguish changes. It could be rolled into a function that is run after the `orders_tmp` table is created.  Other option, assuming warehouse is using Postgres, is to use [Pg FDW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) to set up a link.

Comment: Have you considered "views" to solve your problem? I think with "views" you can prepare code for the migration and perform switching between tables.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://brandur.org/fragments/postgres-table-rename